# Adapt ViewPager to the height of the ImageView

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, layout, android-viewpager, imageview

I have been searching for information but I still don't figure out how to adapt the height of the ViewPager to the height of the ImageView (not using scaleXY on the ImageView to scale the image to the size of the ViewPager). What I would like is to maintain the size and the image as it is and get rid of the space above and under the image. Thank you in advance!

MultipleImagesDialogFragment.kt

```
class MultipleImagesDialogFragment:DialogFragment() {

private lateinit var arrayImageURLs: Array<String>
private lateinit var binding: DialogMultipleImagesBinding

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

    binding = DialogMultipleImagesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    //Get the array with the images of the product, built interpolating the product 'prodid' field
    arrayImageURLs = arguments?.getStringArray(URL_KEY) as Array<String>
    Log.d(TAG, "Image URL: $arrayImageURLs")

    // Initialize ViewPager
    val viewPager = binding.viewPager

    // Initializing the ViewPagerAdapter
    val viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(requireContext(), arrayImageURLs)

    // Set Adapter for ViewPager
    viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter

    // Setup dot's indicator
    val tabLayout = binding.tabLayoutIndicator
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    //Downloading the main image of the product from the URL

    //Create the Dialog
    val view = binding.root
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        .setView(view)
        .create()

    //Listener for the ImageButton to dismiss the dialog ('x')
    binding.ibDismissDialog.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    return dialog
}


companion object {
    val TAG = MultipleImagesDialogFragment::class.java.simpleName
    const val URL_KEY = "URL_key"
}

internal class ViewPagerAdapter(context: Context, images: Array<String>) :
    PagerAdapter() {
    // Context object
    private var context: Context

    // Array of images
    private var images: Array<String>

    // Layout Inflater
    private var mLayoutInflater: LayoutInflater
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        // return the number of images
        return images.size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object` as FrameLayout
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        // inflating the item.xml
        val itemView: View = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_image, container, false)

        // referencing the image view from the imageViewMain.xml file
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_single_image) as ImageView



        // setting the image in the imageView

        Glide.with(itemView)
            .load(images[position])
            .transform(RoundedCorners(20))
            .error(R.drawable.no_image)
            .into(imageView)


        // Adding the View
        Objects.requireNonNull(container).addView(itemView)
        return itemView
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, obj: Any) {
        container.removeView(obj as FrameLayout)
    }

    // Viewpager Constructor
    init {
        this.context = context
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        this.images = images
    }
}
}
```

dialog_multiple_images.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_dismiss_dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ib_dismiss_dialog_contentDescription" />


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ib_dismiss_dialog"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

single_image.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- image viwer to view the images -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_single_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]